# Excel is converting a number to a date when importing csv file

Tags: excel, csv

Im using excel to convert and clean up some csv files and when im importing the files to excel, excel seems to want to convert numbers from one of the columns to a date. For example a column that I am converting is the employee_size column, where some of the rows would have a number like 1-4, excel then reads it as 4-Jan. Is there anyway I can fix this issue, its becoming quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column format (step 3 of the Import Wizard).

Comment: That is - use the `Data >> From text` method instead of just opening the files directly in Excel.

Comment: Thank you guys, i will implement this on my next task.